# Recursion in math-mode \text

Tags: math-mode

Why does this:

```
$\text{a^b}$
```

produce this:

[image: Example output of $\text{a^b}]

Tested [here](http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=%5Cdpi%7B300%7D&space;%5Clarge&space;%5Ctext%7Ba%5Eb%7D), but my copy of MiKTeX 2.9 (pdflatex) fails with an error.

Comment: This shouldn't work at all, since you cannot use math in text.

Comment: I think this is off-topic. The only possible answer is that the site you linked to doesn't work properly; you could ask the site owners why this is.

Comment: sounds like an aftermath of some underlying `\mathchoice`

Comment: Since the service provides a web interface that produces images of code snippets - even when it contains errors - there must be some magic that happens in the back. For example `\hello$a_{\world b}` produced `$a_b$` without error.

Answer (score 1):

I only get a blank page, after trying with TeX Live 2010, 2011, 2012 and 2013. I'm not saying that I don't trust you, but that I can't reproduce the behavior.

What I *do* get is a long series of error messages (forty-one, to be precise), which are obvious, because LaTeX expects text mode material in the argument of `\text`. You get an error with

```
\mbox{a^b}
```

because of the same reason.

What the site does under the hood is not known; but the four object aren't too much of a surprise, because `\text` *does* typeset four boxes, then printing only one. The site is trying hard to get some output; for instance, a single backslash outputs $.

Comment: I can see it with TL2013, Linux and Firefox